# Load DataTable where select in Laravel 8 with yajra datatables

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I need to load a DataTable where the input value equals the value in the database. I try to use this function but not work correctly.

**Controller**

```
public function getit(Request $request)
{
    $shp_no = $request->shp_no_for_it;
    $data = Item::select('*')->where('shp_no_for_it', $shp_no)->get();
    
    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
            $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
            
            return $btn;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

**Script**

```
$('#search_button').click(function(){
    $(function () {
        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('getit') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

**Input**

```
<input type="title" class="form-control" id="shp_no_for_it" name="shp_no_for_it">
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('getit', [ItemController::class, 'getit'])->name('getit');
```

Comment: show input button form also and mention what error in the mentioned code

Comment: try this `$data = Item::query();` and then `Datatables::eloquent($data->where('shp_no_for_it', $shp_no))->addIndexColumn().........`

Comment: Or, it will work too `$data = Item::where('shp_no_for_it', $shp_no):` then `return Datatables::eloquent($data)....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have not passed data in ajax. So first create a function to datatable

```
function itemDataTable(param={}){
     dataTable = $('#itemTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,

         ajax: {
             url: "{{ route('getit') }}",
             type: 'get',
             headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
             data: param,


         },
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });

    return dataTable;
}
```

Then on page load call data table

```
$(function () {
  itemDataTable();
});
```

and on click search button

```
$('#search_button').click(function(){
    var param={
        shp_no_for_it:$('#shp_no_for_it').val();
    }
    itemDataTable(param)
});
```

and in controller if you are using server side processing then no need to call get() .But add following

```
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
```

and in controller

```
public function getit(Request $request)
{
    $shp_no = $request->shp_no_for_it;
            $data = Item::select('*') ->where('shp_no_for_it', $shp_no);
            return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                            $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
}
```

and in html table

```
<table class="table table-bordered data-table col-md-12" id="itemTable">
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. but when i use it i get this error Uncaught TypeError: dataTable is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (view-items:718)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3).. please tell me how can i fix this.. Thanks

Comment: @PolesAnwar can you show full view blade code

Comment: <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered data-table col-md-12">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: @PolesAnwar please add to question full code of that page

Comment: @PolesAnwar updated  answer also check iy

Comment: It,s worked now.. thank you.. i remove this function ($(function () {
  itemDataTable();
});) and in search_button add this ( $('#itemTable').dataTable().fnClearTable();
    $('#itemTable').dataTable().fnDraw();
    $('#itemTable').dataTable().fnDestroy(); ) ..Thank you for your help

Comment: @PolesAnwar you can pass  destroy: true, like this also